# OpenCv Emgu - How to set grayscaleimage pixel intensity

Tags: opencv, grayscale, emgucv

I'm trying to initialize a new `Image<Gray,float>` and set all the pixel values manually based on the gradients. My question is: How to set the pixel gray intensity. It won't accept double precision numbers.

```
if (i >= 1 && j >= 1 && grayTextIm[i, j].Intensity + gthres < grayTextIm[i, j].Intensity && grayTextIm[i, j].Intensity < grayTextIm[i, j].Intensity-gthres)
{
    gradIm[i, j].Intensity = 1.0;
}
else
{
    gradIm[i,j]= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the `intensity` property. However, you can substitute the gray pixel for another of different intensity: `gradIm[i, j] = new Gray();`